# ¿Se puede extraer el valor de una variable declarada en un input dentro de un form?

Tags: javascript, formularios, jsp

estoy intentando manipular los datos de una variable que se utiliza dentro del imput que a su vez pertenece a un form.
¿es posible extraer en una función JavaScript el contenido de la variable y poder modificarlo para devolverlo en el action del form?

```
<form action="/buscador">

 <input type="hidden" id="id_grupoPagina" name="grupoPagina" 
                                        value="<c:out value="${results.grupoPagina}" escapeXml="true"/>" />
```

quiero extraer la variable id_grupoPagina, sumarle 10 y pasarla por el action "/buscador"

Comment: He visto que asi se pueden extrar los datos de un input hiden:                                    ´´´var campo=window.frames[0].document.getElementById("valorcampo").value;
var valorimg_up=window.frames[0].document.getElementById(campo).value;```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El input, aunque esté oculto, es parte del DOM, por lo que puedes utilizar `document.getElementById()` para obtener su referencia y, a partir de allí, acceder a sus propiedades, por ejemplo así:

```html
<form action="/buscador">
  <label for="prueba">Prueba</label>
  <input id="prueba" />
  <input type="hidden" id="id_grupoPagina" name="grupoPagina" value="Esto es una prueba" escapeXml="true" />
  <button id="boton">¡haz clic para cambiar valor!</button>
  <button type="submit">¡haz clic para enviar!</button>
</form>  
<script>
  let boton = document.getElementById("boton");
  
  boton.addEventListener("click", buttonClick);
  
  function buttonClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let idGrupo = document.getElementById("id_grupoPagina");
    idGrupo.value = idGrupo.value + "/";
    console.log(idGrupo.value);
  }
  
</script>
```

Puedes probar mi ejemplo aquí mismo haciendo clic en el botón *"Ejecutar"*.

Comment: ¿De esta forma lo estaría enviando la variable por el action al hacer click en el botón?

Comment: Mientras escribía la respuesta olvidé que no solo quieres recuperar, sino manipular. He actualizado mi ejemplo. El valor que se enviará en el formulario es el que tenga cuando se haga el _submit_ del mismo. El ejemplo ahora le va agregarndo caracteres, para que puedas probarlo facilmente.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: Si no quisiera poner el botón que modifica el valor y quisiera añadirle la funcionalidad de que me añada " / "  al hacer submit. ¿Enviaría el resultado al action directamente? o tendría que dirigirlo de alguna forma. Le agradezco su colaboración

Comment: @AlejandroR, veo que hasta ahora no tienes ninguna respuesta aceptada, en las diferentes preguntas que has hecho. Si sabes [que hacer cuando alguien contesta tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), ¿verdad?. Si no sabes como, te invito a repetir el [tour].

Comment: @AlejandroR, puedes hacerlo todo en un solo paso, yo lo he puesto aquí separado para que se entienda mejor mi respuesta. Si quitas la llamada a `preventDefault()` en el evento, el formulario se va a enviar con el valor que tenga el `input` al terminar de ejecutarse el código del mismo.

Comment: Vale ósea que si le quito el preventDefault() envía el action con el valor modificado de la funcion

Comment: si, es correcto.

Comment: El nombre de la función podría ser el que uno quiera o debe de ser "buttonClick"

Comment: El qué tu quieras, siempre que sea un identificador válido. Podrías probar antes de preguntar, o buscar la documentación también.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias por la ayuda y la paciencia. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Claro que puedes obtener el valor del input.

Si usas jquery:

```
$("[name='grupoPagina']").val();
```

Ahí estaría extrayendo el valor del input obteniendolo por el nombre de tu input.

con el valor, una vez obtenido, ya podrías hacer lo que quieras, guardarlo en una variable o lo que necesites

También lo puedes hacer como te dice el comentario justo debajo de tu pregunta, pero eso es javascript puro.

Espero haberte guiado.

Un saludo

Comment: ¿y si quiero enviar el resultado por el mismo action? ¿Cómo le digo el action para hacer el submit?

Comment: @AlejandroR entonces deberías de enviar ese valor como parámetro por la URL, en el action solo va la ruta a donde van las acciones. Pero si quieres hacer eso si o si, deberías de pasarlo como parámetro a esa ruta mas o menos así: /buscador?parametro1=param